# PyGTK label set cursor function?

Tags: python, cursor, focus, label, pygtk

I have a selectable gtk.label, and I would like to have the cursor in the label when the program starts. Is there a function that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible, but if it is, then

```
label.grab_focus()
```

will do it. Make sure to set the `gtk.CAN_FOCUS` flag first. [Documentation here.](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--grab-focus)